# Angular - How to load selected key and value from dropdown into another text inputs on change

Tags: angular

In Angular-15 project I am displaying the selected value from a dropdown on change:

**component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControlOptions, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from "ngx-bootstrap/modal";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { UsernameValidator } from 'src/app/shared/validators/username-validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-create',
  templateUrl: './customer-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-create.component.scss']
})
export class CustomerCreateComponent {

  isSubmitted = false;
  isLoading = false;
  userIdentifiers!: any[];
  event: EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {;
    this.loadAllUserIdentifiers();
  }

  loadAllUserIdentifiers(){
    this.customerService.getTransferAuthDropdown().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.userIdentifiers = res.data;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    })
  }

  onClose() {
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
  }
}
```

**component.html:**

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id">id</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='id'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userIdentifier">userIdentifier</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='userIdentifier'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="userIdentifier">User Identifier<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <ng-select [items]="userIdentifiers" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="userIdentifier" placeholder="Select User Identifier" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" required formControlName="authId">
    </ng-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Apart from the dropdown list, I also have two separate text input fields as shown above.

How do I display bindValue and bindLabel from the dropdown into:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='id'>
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='userIdentifier'>
```

respectively

Comment: You can patch the corresponding form field value after selecting a value from the list. See: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **component.ts** you are not providing a form, so I will have to assume it looks something like this:

```
public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl(null),
  userIdentifier: new FormControl(null),
  authId: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
});
```

Working from that you can set a (change) event on your select like so (see at the end of the line):

```
<ng-select [items]="userIdentifiers" [selectOnTab]="true" [searchable]="true" bindValue="id" bindLabel="userIdentifier" placeholder="Select User Identifier" [multiple]="false" [clearable]="true" formControlName="authId" (change)="populateOtherFields()">
```

Then you can handle this in your **component.ts**:

```
public populateOtherFields() {
  const selectedUserIdentifier = this.userIdentifiers.find(userIdentifier => {
    return userIdentifier.id === this.form.get('authId').value;
  });

  if (selectedUserIdentifier) {
    this.form.get('id').setValue(selectedUserIdentifier.id);
    this.form.get('userIdentifier').setValue(selectedUserIdentifier.name); // I am putting "name" here, because from the code you shared there is no way to tell which property this should be.
  }
}
```